# Unhandled exception thrown by PhotoChooserTask

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I've got this code and I'm using it to show a button which allows the user to choose an image from his library and use it as a background for my app.

So I create a `PhotoChooserTask`, set it to show the camera and bind it to a method that has to be executed when the task is completed.
The button will start the task by showing the `PhotoChooserTask`.
The action to do on complete is quite easy, I've just got to set a boolean value and update an image source.

```
PhotoChooserTask pct_edit = new PhotoChooserTask();
pct_edit.ShowCamera = true;
pct_edit.Completed += pct_edit_Completed;
Button changeImageButton = new Button { Content = "Change Image" };
changeImageButton.Tap += (s, e) =>
{
    pct_edit.Show();
};


void pct_edit_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            bi.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            IsRebuildNeeded = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it won't show the `PhotoChooserTask` but it will give me an exception, taking me to

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

in `App.xaml.cs`.

This looks weird as I've got another `PhotoChooserTask` in the same class and this one works fine.

What's wrong with it?

VisualStudio won't even tell me what's the exception and so there's no way to figure it out!

EDIT:

I just found out that the exception is thrown when I call

```
pct_edit.Show();
```

in the button's tap event.

Answer (score 1):

You should be defining your chooser as a field in your class. It's a requirement that you have page scope for the PhotoChooser. You then subscribe to it in your constructor. This is stated on the [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
class SomeClass
{
   readonly PhotoChooserTask pct_edit = new PhotoChooserTask();

   SomeClass()
   {
       pct_edit.ShowCamera = true;
       pct_edit .Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(pct_edit_Completed);
   }
}
```

Comment: That's how I'm already doing (I've not pasted the whole class but the task is declared as a field in my class). The problem is that the task won't work if I call it from inside the button

Comment: Have you tried showing the task from a different event? Perhaps the problem is actually with your button.

Comment: I've changed the event from `Tap` to `Click` but nothing changes. The task is shown but the exception is thrown so that the app crashes and so the task can't be completed

Comment: I meant a different event in your application that is not linked to the button. Have you tried wrapping a dispatcher call around the show method? I don't see it specified in the MSDN, but you may have to be on the UI thread to be able to show choosers.

Comment: Got it. If called outside the event linked to the button, the task actually works. But I still don't get what's wrong with the button

Comment: I'm not sure either. I do this in my app but the button is generated in xaml and the click event is a standard method. Maybe try those changes and see if it corrects the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try` to check what is the problem

```
changeImageButton.Tap += (s, e) =>
{
    try
    {
       PhotoChooserTask pct_edit = new PhotoChooserTask();
       pct_edit.ShowCamera = true;
       pct_edit.Completed += (s,e) =>
       {
           if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
           {
              var bi = new BitmapImage() // maybe you didn't initialize bi?
              bi.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
              IsRebuildNeeded = true;
           }
       }
       pct_edit.Show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Message.Show(ex.Message);
    }
};
```

Put brakepoint on `Message`, then you can check everything inside `ex`.