# Stop a thread if it takes too long

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8, thread-abort

I am new in Windows Phone development and I am trying to create a windows phone app using C#

```
Thread t = new Thread(doaheavywork);
t.Start();

if (!t.Join(1000)) // give the operation 1s to complete
{
    t.Abort();
}
```

I cannot alter the doaheavywork function.

I just need the result to be omputed within 1 or 2 seconds, since sometimes it may run for very long time.

I have read using abort is the wrong way.

I am using the above in a PhotoChooserTask complete function. First run executes fine. That is, when I click the button to select a photo, the doaheavywork function doesn't exceed 1 sec. But if I try for the second time, the PhotoChooserTask just throws an exception and stops.

Is it because I aborted the process in 1st run? Or anything else? Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Without seeing your exception, we're not gonna be able to help you.

Comment: Could it be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105301/unhandled-exception-thrown-by-photochoosertask ?

Comment: Consider using `TPL` and this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/23478628/1808494 You really shouldn't be instanciating threads unless you know what you are doing. Threadpool is your friend (but TPL is your BFF).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Abort()` causes the thread to be destroyed completely. If you are generating a new thread each time like in your example, then it will work. However if you are using the same `t` object, then you need to create a new thread object, you can't run `.Start()` on an aborted thread.

However the fact you are aborting a thread is a concern. What happens with the application when it does take more than 2 seconds. Should you be showing the user, please wait, its taking longer than expected. Doing that in the `if` block is where to do it. `.Join()` won't stop the thread even if it doesn't manage to join.

**Edit**

You have 2 options you might want to consider in rewriting this section:

1. BackgroundWorker - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx
2. Thread Task - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221403%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Tasks seem to be the appropriate solution in your scenario.

Comment: +1 for `Abort` being a concern (if not a code smell). One can't emphasize enough, how fundamentally wrong the notion of suspending, resuming and aborting threads in order to control one's program flow is.

Comment: Actually come to think of it. This isn't at all an answer. It is correct that the OP is doing it wrong. But @Adam you haven't provided an alternative. Perhaps that might be why there is a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

One approach maybe be to consider using a Task and having a CancellationToken passed in to it from a CancellationTokenSource instantiated against a specific timespan - 2 seconds.  That way when the the time specified has elapsed, the CancellationToken, passed to the Task, will be signaled and then appropriate action can be taken.

Comment: Second that, you should be using the `Task` class, which is the preferred way to run code on separate threads since .NET 4.0. Again, you keep us in the dark without showing more code and the exception details.